# Jquery do action on pressing enter or hitting "OK" on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile

I have an input field:

```
<input type="text" id="awesome-input" />
```

And I'd like to do an action when the user hits enter:

```
$("#awesome-input").on('keydown',function(e){
  if(e.which == 13)
    console.log("did stuff!");
}
```

**However**, I'd also like to do the same action when a mobile user hits "ok" after typing on a touch screen. My first thought was the `submit` event, but that only works if I wrap it in a form, which I'd rather not do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out all the phones I've tried so far will trigger a click event where `e.which == 13`, so really it already works.